# Swift code not taking me to error line on click

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

So i'm getting some errors while working on swift and when I click on the errors xcode is not taking me to the relevant piece of code. Is there a setting I have to enable? Is there a bug in Xcode?

Comment: that seemed to fix it. thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When Xcode starts to behave erratically, the first thing to try to:

1. Identify the derived data folder (it can be identified by going to the [Locations preferences](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-locations_preferences/About/About.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010523-CH1-SW1) and clicking on the [image: derived] button next to "Derived Data").
2. Exit Xcode.
3. Empty the derived data folder.
4. Restart Xcode.

Comment: Also file a bug with Apple via BugReporter and tell them to do their job, because instability of Swift and Xcode is a big waste of everyone's time and has persisted too long.